# How do I create a spatial filter on a layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-2

I have a layer that draws points in a PostgreSQL (PostGIS) database. The problem is, all  points in the table are being drawn. I want to limit the points drawn to a spatial query. How do I limit the points being drawn on the layer to the results of a spatial query? Where do I specify the spatial query?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options (in no particular order):

1. You could define a view in PostGIS and load the view as a layer in QGIS.
2. You could open DBManager and perform the spatial query in the SQL window and check the box under the results window to "`Load as new Layer`".
3. Perform your spatial query and save the selected features as a new dataset for use in your map.
4. Perform your spatial query and create a new attribute field to hold a Boolean value.  Then use `Layer->Query` and set the standard filter to your Boolean value (this will hide all the other points).
5. Set the display style of your points to be 100% transparent and then perform the spatial query.  Your points from the spatial query will appear in the default selection colour - you can change that in `Project->Project Properties->General`

Comment: For a PostGIS layer you can also define a conditional spatial query in the Layer (Provider) Filter: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434781/spatial-queries-with-qgis-provider-feature-filter-layer-filter