# Spatial queries with QGIS provider feature filter (layer filter)

Tags: qgis, layers, query, filter

QGIS offers the option to use layer filters: `Layer Properties > Source > Provider Feature Filter`, [see documentation: Query Builder](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder).

As far as I can see, this filter is only able to filter based on attributes, but does not have the option to define spatial queries. So what is possible using e.g. a virtual layer or a PostGIS query (filtering let's say all  polygons from layer 1 that are disjoint from layer 2), is **not** possible with this Provider Feature Filter.

Is this correct?

*I'm just asking if I miss something or not, so the answer I'm looking for is just a confirmation or falsification of my assumption that there is no possibility for spatial queries (like `disjoint`) there. I know how to do it in PostGIS or with Virtual Layer, so this is not part of the question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do spatial queries with it, but not depending on another layer. But you can do filters like `ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(geom,4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(33,22),4326))` assuming you are working with a PostGIS layer. So you need to **create** the geometry inside the the query builder. In this example, `geom` is the name of the geometry column of the filtered layer.

Its exactly as the docs state:

> The filter is made at the data provider (OGR, PostgreSQL, MSSQL…)
> level. So the syntax depends on the data provider (DateTime is for
> instance not supported for the ESRI Shapefile format).

Comment: Is there a definitive and easy to scan table of the providers and their capabilities in terms of filtering?

Comment: in this line: How do I know, which expressions are possible for DXF-files?